# How to insert a date into a google spreadsheet?

Tags: google-docs

In a google spreadsheet I define some vertical cells with Format 'Date' as '29.5.2019' (i.e. day.month.year). In the cell below I define a formula

```
=A3+7
```

to get the date one week later. But no matter what I enter in "A2", I get an error like:

```
Function ADD parameter 1 expects number values. But '29.5.2019' is a text and cannot be coerced to a number.
```

So although I think that the format in A2 is a date, the spreadsheet thinks its a text. So how to fix that?

Answer (score 0):

Date should be in the format dd/mm/yyyy.

Comment: Ah I MUST enter the date as MM/DD/YYYY (the stupid US format), but THEN I can change the format. Not obvious at all.

Comment: @Alex Good to know